# how to change model data when i press a switch in SAPUI5?

Tags: json, model, switch-statement, odata, sapui5

I have a view, how can i change the model data when i press a switch button? For example if it's a true state, change model Json and if it´s false ODATA. Many thanks!

I have a idea, but i cant how to implement!

For example

```
changeModel:function (e){

    if(e.getParameter==="true"){ //MODEL JSON OFFLINE }
    else { //ODATA MODEL  }

}


changeModel:function (e){

    if(e .getParameter==="true"){ //MODEL JSON OFFLINE } else { //ODATA MODEL }

}


changeModel:function (e){

    if(e.getParameter==="true"){ //MODEL JSON OFFLINE } else { //ODATA MODEL     }

}
```

Comment: As an view what are you using eg list, table, form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting this, then the structure of your odata model and json model must be same, meaning the entity sets, attributes etc. So, if this is done, let's attempt this :

Step 1: have a alias for model say currentModel and set it's alias as  "currentModel".

Step 2: bind your view with currentModel alias ( like `<Text text="currentModel>name" />` )

Step 3: say I default make currentModel is jsonModel.

`this.getView().setModel(jsonModel, "currentModel");`

Step 4:  now on press of switch, all I gotta do : 
`this.getView().setModel(oDataModel, "currentModel");`

This might lead to data inconsistencies. Also, while sending data you will need to check whats the current model.

Let me know if this helps.